# VMWare PowerCli - issue in connecting the remote ESX host - ResourceUnavailable: (:) [Get-VMHost], ViServerConnectionException

Tags: vmware, powercli, esx

I am trying to connect remote ESX host using PowerCli Version 6.5 release1 to get all VMs from Windows 10 system.
while executing connect-VIServer I am not getting any output or errors. But while execute get-VMHost I get below error message.  Vsphere client can  connect to the ESX host using the same credentials . Please help fix powercli issue.

```
PS C:\> Connect-VIServer 10.44.6.45
PS C:\> Get-VMHost
Get-VMHost : 1/25/2019 6:51:43 PM       Get-VMHost              You are not currently connected to any servers. Please connect first
using a Connect cmdlet.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-VMHost
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [Get-VMHost], ViServerConnectionException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Core_BaseCmdlet_NotConnectedError,VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Cmdlets.Commands.GetVMHost

PS C:\>
```

Comment: Run connect-VIserver with -verbose and paste content.

Answer (score 0):

Based no your code, I don't believe you're connected to the 10.44.6.45 host. I would expect to see a response with the connected host and the credentials being used to establish that connection whereas your code indicates no response at all.

You may want to attempt the following instead:

```
$creds = Get-Credential # Note: This will prompt you to enter your credentials
Connect-VIServer -Server 10.44.6.45 -Credential $creds
```